# How to make a button multiplier

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a bot that would create a number of buttons based on a for loop, this is what I want to succeed in doing:
(I'm using discord_components, for some reason, there isn't a tag for that, idk why)

```
import discord
from discord_components import *

client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)
client.remove_command('help')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ok")
    DiscordComponents(client)
@client.command()
async def create_buttons(ctx, numofbuttons: int, label):
    buttons = []
    for i in range(numofbuttons):
    buttons.append(Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue,label=label))
    await ctx.send("this message has buttons!",components=buttons)
    a = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    await ctx.send(f"{a.label} was clicked!")
```

this didn't work, I assumed because when you add a function to a list, you are adding what it returns instead of the function itself(if you know what I mean, sorry I'm not an expert at this stuff). is there any way to fix this? the problem I'm dealing with is more complex and absolutely has to include a for loop. I created the sample above for a simpler version that is much more easier to read. I am using "await client.wait_for" because for the real project, I need a way to get the button's label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, name the function properly, put an underscore between `create` and `button`

Marking the `numberofbuttons` parameter as int removes raising of `TypeError`.

Putting the `*` before `label` marks the `label` parameter as a multi-line parameter.

You can use the view module to add buttons, this is an example:

```
import discord
from discord.ui import Button, View

client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.command()
async def create_buttons(ctx, numofbuttons: int, *, label: str):
    buttons = []
    view = View()
    for i in range(numofbuttons):
       view.add_item(Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label=label))
    await ctx.send("this message has buttons!",view=view)
```

Comment: I've tried discord.ui once, but I said that "module discord.ui is not found", I tried to install it and everything but no help. there is something called discord_ui but I don't know if it's the same

Comment: @TitanWarrior Check that you're installing the development version of dpy

Comment: Finally figured out how to make development dpy work thanks